# Which JBoss component implements which Java EE 6 standard

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x

For some time I've been struggling to find info about which component of JBoss AS 7 (the latest version) implements which Java EE 6 spec. The best I found is, which lists the standards implemented by JBoss EAP (JBoss AS productized by redhat), but there is no info about which component(s) implement which spec: https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/articles/113373

Do you know about where to find this info / can you please provide this info?

Comment: asking about features of a product of your own employer on SO. nice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are projects I remember that implement Java EE6 specs

CDI - Weld project - http://www.seamframework.org/Weld

JPA - Hibernate - http://www.hibernate.org/

Webservices - JBossWS - http://www.jboss.org/jbossws

Rest JAX-RS - RestEasy - http://www.jboss.org/resteasy

Security - PicketLink, PicketBox - http://www.jboss.org/picketlink , http://www.jboss.org/picketbox

What other information you need?

Comment: After consulting with others in Redhat I found out that this info is nowhere to be found explicitly, in one place. Instead it is scattered on various project sites :(